# Why matplotlib is not displaying the chart with values generated using numpy random array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have written following code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.random.randint(0,10,[1,5])
y=np.random.randint(0,10,[1,5])
x.sort(),y.sort()
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set( title="random data plot", xlabel="x",ylabel="y")
```

I am getting a blank figure. 
Same code prints chart if I manually assign below value to x and y and not use random function.

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[11,22,33,44]
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`x=np.random.randint(0,10,[1,5])` returns an array if you specify the shape as [1,5]. Either you would want `x=np.random.randint(0,10,[1,5])[0]` or `x=np.random.randint(0,10,size = 5)`. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I was generating 2D array and thrn trying to plot. This should have been done with 1D array. x=np.random.randint(0,10, 5) would have sufficed.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib doesn't plot markers by default, only a line. As per @Can comment, matplotlib then interprets your (1, 5) array as 5 different datasets each with 1 point, so there is no line as there is no second point.

If you add a marker to your plot function then you can see the data is actually being plotted, just probably not as you wish:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.random.randint(0,10,[1,5])
y=np.random.randint(0,10,[1,5])
x.sort(),y.sort()
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.plot(x,y, marker='.') # <<< marker for each point added here
ax.set( title="random data plot", xlabel="x",ylabel="y")
```

Comment: Thanks, @'Paddy Harrison'. Your answer opened new learning for me. I thought 2D couldn't be plotted.